# Stolen Phone - How to Know if iPhone sound was triggered/un-triggered

Tags: iphone

I accidentally left my phone in an Uber. It is still turned on and I have been using the Find My iPhone app to track it - the Uber driver claims to not have it in his car, however, the location changes every few minutes and going to all bars throughout the night - therefore leading me to believe it is still in the Uber. If I play the sound through the Find My iPhone app, is there a way to tell if someone has turned off the sound once it begins playing? I know you automatically receive an email that a sound was played, but I'd like to know if you can find out if someone turned the sound off.

Answer (score 1):

The sound will play on the device regardless of the silent switch, and when the device plays a sound it reports back to iCloud and you will receive an email saying that the sound has been played. While there's no way to be sure that anybody heard it, you can safely assume that the sound was played if you get that email.